# Repeating Javascript Slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow, repeat

I have a working slideshow, but at the end of the images it just stops. Is there something I can add or change to my code (below) that could have it repeat or loop continuously?

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }

  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }


  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/p9djL158/. Always try to create a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example in your question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

> setTimeout() triggers the expression only once whilesetInterval()
>   keeps triggering expressionregularly after the given interval of time.
>   (unless you tell it to stop).

=> `setInterval(showSlides, 2000)`

Comment: For some reason, that removes the third image. It cycles through the first two and then stops.